# Running heroku run command generates the SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty error

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my Django project using Heroku, but now stuck with the empty SECRET_KEY problem when I run the `heroku run python manage.py syncdb` command:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "manage.py", line 10, in 
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 330, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 190, in fetch_command
>       klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 40, in load_command_class
>       module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 37, in import_module
>       **import**(name)
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 4, in 
>       from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/**init**.py", line 7, in 
>       from django.middleware.csrf import rotate_token
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/csrf.py", line 14, in 
>       from django.utils.cache import patch_vary_headers
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/cache.py", line 26, in 
>       from django.core.cache import caches
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/cache/**init**.py", line 34, in 
>       if DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS not in settings.CACHES:
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 48, in **getattr**
>       self._setup(name)
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 44, in _setup
>       self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 113, in **init**
>       raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
>   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.

However, running `python manage.py syncdb` is totally fine. In my `settings.py` file, I even wrote the SECRET_EKY explicitly as:

```
    import os

    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

    SECRET_KEY = '*$_99!t5u&#w&9boeq()=obq@rjdsfasdfa#8hp_5s%h-mh(hk'`
```

I still got the same problem. I wondered if the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE was missing, but running `heroku config` gave me (I replaced the information with xxx):

> DATABASE_URL:           xxx
>
> DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: xxx
>
> SECRET_KEY:             xxx

It seems that the relevant environment variables do exist. I really hope you could give me some suggestions. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: First of all you should change your secret key now. Second, please give a description of the error because no one can guess what the error might be.

Comment: @enpenax I have added more information, please let me know if there is anything else I need to provide. Thank you.

Comment: are you sure your settings file is found and loaded?

Comment: This most probably is related to django not able to find its settings file and not specifically related to the ``SECRET_KEY`` setting. The problem is that when django loads it tries to read the secret key from the settings file, but if no such file is loaded it will just fail with the SECRET_KEY must not be empty error.

Comment: @Serafeim When I run python `manage.py`, it works; the error only occurs when I run  `heroku run manage.py`, so it must be something about my hekoru setup, but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: @enpenax I'm sure it is loaded when I don't use `hekoru run` command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced this issues a while ago. The following command resolved the issue for me

command: `heroku config:set SECRET_KEY="your_secret_key"`

Answer (score 0):

Might be a stupid question, but are you running `heroku run python manage.py syncdb`?

If so, I am very confident, that your settings module is not loaded.

This could potentially have one of the following reasons:

- Your settings module is not where Django expects it
  (*but you are saying manage.py can find it*)
- You have another config, that overshadows your config settings
  (*for example a local.py settings module for development settings*)

Did you do any modification to `manage.py` or `wsgi.py`?

I edit this answer if I can think of more.

Comment: Yes, the problem only occurs when I run `heroku run python manage.py syncdb`, and running `python manage.py syncdb` is totally fine. I do have a local_settings.py file, but I added it in my .gitignore file, so it shouldn't be a problem. I did modify wsgi.py file according to Heroku's tutorial from `application = `get_wsgi_application()` to `application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())`. I didn't touch manage.py.

Answer (score 0):

You can as well go to your app on your heroku dashboard, click on **settings**, then, scroll downwards; you'll find the button **Reveal Config Vars**. Add the SECRET_KEY and it's value as instructed. You can as well, add other secret properties required by your application.